# mysql select query very slow when using where clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users`")) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      }
}
```

When I use the above code query works fine..

But when I use the following code mysql is very slow.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name IS NULL")) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      }
}
```

Can someone tell me why and how to make that query faster?

Comment: define "very slow". And how many rows you have in the table

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have 5000 rows in the table

Comment: -1 for not providing certain numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to make the query run faster.

1. Avoid `*` as it first look for all the column then it gives them out.
   Solution - Use the attribute name manually such as:

   ```
   Select `name`, `age`, `XYZ` from `users` where `name` IS NULL
   ```
2. Use [**INDEX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the query.
3. Use [**EXPLAIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) to find out which index could be used and which index is actually used. Create an appropriate index if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an index on the `name` column to speed things up.

Comment: index is probably the answer, although depends on the rest of the db setup, and what else will be done with the table (ie is this a one off SELECT performed once a week, compared to 1,000 writes a day...? etc). If you have another column that is already indexed, using that as a clause in your select can speed it up, if possible, this also depends on your setup and other queries, and is not always practical/possible/recommended